# IPtables on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: iptables

I've problem with iptables on ubuntu 12.4.

I type `ufw status`, it show result `Status: inactive`
but I type `iptbles -L -nv`, it still shows many rules, and these rules are running.

I can't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two slightly different things. The Linux kernel has a packet filtering system called *netfilter*, whose traditional frontend is *iptables*. You control netfilter by means of iptables.

However, iptables is considered a tad complex for new users, so that Ubuntu provides *ufw*, the *uncomplicated firewall*, for new users unwilling to put in the effort to study iptables.

*ufw* allows a simpler control of netfilter, but this does not mean that it provides the *only* control: you may have simultaneously ufw active, with furthermore some extra rules provided by iptables. Or alternatively, you may control netfilter only through iptables, without ufw even being enabled, which is precisely your case.